# I am have two errors with double score

Tags: c#

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        SortedList<string, double> num2 = new SortedList<string, double>();
        string Name;
        double Score;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name Score:");
           
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Score);
            num2.Add(Name, Score);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name Score:");
            
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Score);
            num2.Add(Name, Score);


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name Score:");
            
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Score);
            num2.Add(Name, Score);


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name Score:");
            
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Score);
            num2.Add(Name, Score);


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name Score:");
            
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Score);
            num2.Add(Name, Score);

        }

        Name = "";
        foreach (var Score in num2) // error with Score
        {
            Name += Name + "\t"
                  + Score + "\n";
            Console.WriteLine(Score);

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:");
            Double Average;
            Double Curve;
            Average = Score / 5;    // wont average.
            Curve = 75 - Average;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I am tried to declare the Score and Name for the reader to use at the top before the sort list function.
And I got an error on the line of the comments. Basically, what im trying to do is set the sort list to read 5 scores and Names. Then I use the 5 scores and Names to find the average and Curve. So when I try to do this I get an error. Im also having trouble with the for each loop. How can I fix this program?

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` isn't working because `Score` is defined as a double already further up in the scope of your Main method (resulting in a syntax error).  I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that loop - looks like your maybe trying to output each name and the corresponding score for that name in your `SortedList`:

```cs
foreach (var listItem in num2)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Name: {listItem.Key}  Score: {listItem.Value}");
}
```

As for your other problems, *you definitely do not need 6 separate `for` loops*.  Just make one to read in all of your input:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a Name");
     string name = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a Score");
     double score = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     num2.Add(name, score);
}
```

This will ask the user to supply 5 names and 5 scores. Then to get your average and curve, you can do something like:

```cs
double average = num2.Sum(item => item.Value) / 5;
double curve = 75 - average;
Console.WriteLine($"Average: {average}  Curve: {curve}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

This uses the [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Double__)
to add together all of your `Value`'s in your Sorted List (you may need to add `using System.Linq;` to your file.  No need to wrap this in another `for` loop as far as I can tell.

With your code, despite all of your `for` loops, it *should* still have captured 5 names and scores.  However, when it comes to actually doing something with the values you captured from input, you weren't using them in any way.  Ignoring the `foreach` loop, `Score` would have been set to whatever the last value entered in your 5th `for` loop, explaining why your `Average` wasn't working as expected.

Some other things to note:

- If two identical names are supplied, this will error, since you can't have two items with the same Key in a SortedList.  You'll want to handle that.
- `double.TryParse` will result in the out parameter being set to `0` if the value attempting to be parsed cannot be.  This could cause unexpected results with your average and curve later on.  I switched it to use just `double.Parse` instead, which will throw an error if it cannot parse the value.  You could account for this by doing something like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a Name");
     string name = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a Score");
     double score;
     bool isScoreValid = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out score);

     while (!isScoreValid)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid score.  Please enter a new one");
         isScoreValid = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out score);
     }

     num2.Add(name, score);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it the same way you did  and it still wont calculate the average. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @BurshellAgness how is it wrong? Is it incorrect or is there an error? Share what your error is if you are getting one.